# Subclassing UIViewController causing memory problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am **subclassing UIViewController** to prevent code repetition of my 'masterButtons' and sets of 'subButtons'.

It all appeared to be working beautifully until I realised that **after about 1200 page changes** - navigating between just 3 blank pages (just the buttons and a few other objects showing) **the app will always crash!**

Instruments (+ testing on a device) **does not show any memory leaks, but does show hundreds of instances of these button objects existing!** ('Created & Still Living' filter selected.)
Also, viewDidUnload / didReceiveMemoryWarning are never called, from any of the ViewControllers!

I have not had these problems on other pages in my app (where UIViewController is NOT subclassed).

So it appears the ViewController's contents are being re-created, and any previously created are not being deleted.
**Are there any common pitfalls of subclassing UIViewController that might be causing this?** Is there something I could be missing?

Advice would be greatly appreciated. (**I feel like throwing my mac out of the window with this problem!**)

```
Top_ViewController      (contains 'MasterButtons')
       v
Area1_ViewController    (subclass of TOP_ViewController) (contains 'subButtons', and  a few texts fields etc.)
       v
aPage_ViewController    (subclass of Area1_ViewController)  (currently blank page)
```

(Using ARC and storyboards. The storyboard View Controllers have a respective 'aPage_ViewController' as their class.)

Comment: how/where do you create your buttons? please, show some code...

Comment: Under iOS 6 `viewDidUnload` has been deprecated and will never be called so if you're doing something in there, you might want to look at changing your App's code/behavior to account for these changes to the API.

Comment: Yeah I will be removing the viewDidUnload methods. (I will post some code shortly...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your storyboard in a loop fashion it might happen that you create new `viewControllers` all the time. Each segue transition is creating new `viewController` thus there might be no memory leak but your memory will be consumed.

You should be using either `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController` to move back and forth and never create loops.

Moreover `viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS6, perhaps you ignored warning?

**EDIT:**

Try something like this:

```
-(void)tab1_IsPressed:(UIButton *)paramSender{
    Top_ViewController *target_VC = (Top_ViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page_1"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:target_VC animated:NO];
}
-(void)tab2_IsPressed:(UIButton *)paramSender{
    Top_ViewController *target_VC = (Top_ViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page_2"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:target_VC animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I am using UINavigationController and this technique to change pages:  Top_ViewController *target_VC = (Top_ViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page2"];       
[self.navigationController pushViewController:target_VC animated:NO];    I really hope a new VC is not being created each time! Is there a way to check?

Comment: You can just print `self` in `viewWillAppear` method of you custom view controller like that `NSLog(@"%@", self);`. Then switch between viewControllers and verify this address from console remain the same. I suggest you to create view controllers in Interface Builder instead from code, you can set class attribute to your custom class.

Comment: Are you ever calling `popViewControllerAnimated` method of `navigationController`?

Comment: Thx, will check VC addresses in console remain the same. There are currently view controllers in the storyboard for each page - and each has is own class. But no, I am not using popViewControllerAnimated here. Is that necessary though, as I am  'pushing' the target viewController in?

Comment: Try my changes from EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: I am not sure what was your intention but in your code every time you click tab1 or tab2 `Tab_Buttons_UIView` you create new `viewController` instance and push it to navigation controller. If you want to use the same `viewControllers` every time then keep these pointers somewhere, perhaps in properties and instantiate them only once.

Comment: Unfortunately pop and then push is making it go back!  But I think you might be onto something here (thx)! If I DO already have a VC instantiated, and just want to to navigate to it again, how do I do that? I thought that is what pushViewController did!

Comment: I did your viewWillAppear test, and the pages are indeed from different addresses. So thanks very much for identifying the problem Tomasz! (I will certainly green tick your answer.) But any idea how to navigate to a VC that has already been instantiated?

Comment: As I said earlier instantiate it only once (maybe in `viewDidLoad:`) and keep reference to them both in some property. Then in your tabX_IsPressed use that property in `pushViewController` call. I wonder why you are not using UITabBarController to switch between view controllers like that.

Comment: I really need a UINavigationController in parts of my app, and it doesn't mix so well with UITabController. So I stayed with just UINavigationController. Thanks again for your excellent help Tomasz! Well spotted. (Will buy one of your apps as thanks.) :)